Removing leading `/' from member names error: open .: is a directory
when I tried to copy files from remote kubernetes pod to local machine:
➜  ~ kubectl --kubeconfig=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/admin.conf cp reddwarf-pro/texhub-server-service-675bffc7c5-ws2n5:/app/texhub-server tex
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
Dropping out copy after 0 retries
error: unexpected EOF

I also tried like this:
➜  ~ kubectl --kubeconfig=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/admin.conf cp reddwarf-pro/texhub-server-service-675bffc7c5-ws2n5:app/texhub-server tex
tar: app/texhub-server: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

I have already check the path and file name are correct. this is the remote file info:
root@texhub-server-service-675bffc7c5-ws2n5:/app# ls
libsynctex_parser.so  log  log4rs.yaml  settings.toml  texhub-server
root@texhub-server-service-675bffc7c5-ws2n5:/app# pwd
/app
root@texhub-server-service-675bffc7c5-ws2n5:/app# ll
bash: ll: command not found
root@texhub-server-service-675bffc7c5-ws2n5:/app# ls -alh
total 8.2M
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   17 Jul 25 13:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   84 Jul 25 13:26 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 188K Jul 25 13:18 libsynctex_parser.so
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   40 Jul 25 13:26 log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  496 Jul 23 14:03 log4rs.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  900 Jul 23 14:03 settings.toml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8.0M Jul 25 13:24 texhub-server

Am I missing something? What should I do to copy file from remote kubernetes cluster to local matchin? I have also tried like this:
➜  ~ kubectl --kubeconfig=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/admin.conf cp -n reddwarf-pro texhub-server-service-675bffc7c5-ws2n5:app/texhub-server tex
tar: app/texhub-server: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
➜  ~ kubectl --kubeconfig=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/admin.conf cp -n reddwarf-pro texhub-server-service-675bffc7c5-ws2n5:/app/texhub-server tex
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
Dropping out copy after 0 retries
error: unexpected EOF
➜  ~ kubectl --kubeconfig=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/admin.conf cp -n reddwarf-pro texhub-server-service-675bffc7c5-ws2n5:/app/texhub-server .
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
error: open .: is a directory

I also tried with the full path like this:
➜  ~ kubectl --kubeconfig=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/admin.conf cp reddwarf-pro/texhub-server-service-675bffc7c5-ws2n5:/app/texhub-server /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/texhub-server
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
Dropping out copy after 0 retries
error: unexpected EOF


The target (tex) doesn't have to be a full path? i.e /tmp/tex

the full path still could not work as expect.
